# Как открыть консоль через нативный JS

Tags: javascript

Задался вопросом, как можно указать браузеру, что нужно сымитировать нажатие клавиши F12, допустим есть участок кода, по исполнению которого должна автоматически открываться браузерная консоль разработчика, с JS знаком не так давно, но ответ на свой вопрос нигде не могу найти. Если нет способа сделать это на чистом JS, то все равно будет интересно узнать, как это можно сделать с использованием например NodeJS или каких-нибудь фреймворков. В качестве примера снизу будет блок кода имитирующий создание лестницы, хотелось бы, чтобы после ввода всех значений в промпт, автоматически выводилась консоль, без нажатия на клавишу F12.

```
  
    let stairsAmount = prompt('Enter amount of stairs')   /*Ввод количества лесенок*/
    firstSymbol = prompt('Enter first symbol of stairs')   /*Ввод первого символа*/
    lastSymbol = prompt('Enter last symbol of stairs')    /*Ввод второго символа*/
    for (let i = 0; i <= stairsAmount; i++) {
        lastSymbol = i == 0 ? lastSymbol : firstSymbol + lastSymbol
        console.log(lastSymbol) /*Как раз таки эту консоль я и хочу вывести автоматически*/
        
    }
```

Comment: javascript не имеет доступа к инструментам разработчика браузера

Comment: эх печально( но спасибо